# Definition: What is a two-sided Lie ideal of a Lie algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, ideals, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a subalgebra. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra), $\mathfrak{h}$ is called an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ if it satisfies the condition that $$[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq\mathfrak{h}\text{.}$$

Occasionally I see a notion called "a two-sided Lie ideal" of a Lie algebra (See [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03479.pdf) for an example). How is it defined? Is it the same as an ideal as is defined above?

Comment: Remember that the Lie bracket is anti-symmetric...

Answer (score 2):

A one sided ideal in a Lie algebra is also a two sided ideal. This is because an ideal is a subspace and hence if $[h,g]\in \mathfrak h$ we also have $[g,h]=-[h,g]\in \mathfrak h$.

Comment: Then why in some literature it is called "two-sided"?

Comment: @Zuriel I'm not sure. It's not incorrect, but it is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks! It is now very clear.

Comment: @Zuriel you're welcome.